# Capistrano duplicate tasks for each role

Tags: capistrano, code-duplication

I must be missing something with Capistrano, because I've just started writing capfiles and I'm looking at tons of duplicated code. Consider this

```
role :dev, "dev1", "dev2"
role :prod, "prod1", "prod2"

desc "Deploy the app in dev"
task :deploy_dev, :roles => :dev do
    run "sudo install-stuff"
end

desc "Deploy the app in prod"
task :deploy_prod, :roles => :prod do
    run "sudo install-stuff"
end
```

IMO it's totally reasonable to want to run the exact same task in dev or prod, but from what I can tell, Capistrano would have me write 2 tasks just to specify the different nodes...

Seems like if you could refer to roles on the CLI like

```
cap deploy dev
cap deploy prod
```

there could be a single definition of the 'deploy' task in the capfile, as opposed to a duplicated one for each set of servers.

Is there a way to write a task once and specify the role dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [multistage extension](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-Multistage-Extension). While fairly easy to set up the tasks you need yourself, the multistage extension will do it all for you.

If you'd rather do it yourself, see the [calling tasks](https://github.com/stefanooldeman/capistrano-handbook/wiki/Building-Blocks-Variables-&-Tasks#calling-tasks) section of the handbook. The trick is that you can invoke different tasks in order from the command line.

Comment: Actually, digging into this today, it appears I'm too stupid to get what I want. Essentially I want a variable to populate the :roles section of a task. My thought is to chain tasks, but I'm not sure if it's possible to set the value of a variable in the first task and use it for the :roles of a subsequent task. Is that possible? Either way, looks like I'm jumping ship and heading to fabric. Found [what I need](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387407/does-python-fabric-support-dynamic-set-env-hosts) in under 30 minutes! Capistrano seems too tightly coupled to ruby projects for my needs.

Comment: I don't really see how this is different from `cap dev deploy`, but whatever serves your needs. Seems to be the exact same solution, as far as I can see.

Comment: I don't have a ruby project, so I don't have a deploy task that the multistage extension can parameterize. Nor do I want to put a config directory in any of the projects I'm deploying for the sake of Capistrano. If I could figure out how to parameterize the :roles I'd be down to stick with Capistrano, but the documentation isn't helping me figure it out.