# fabric env.hosts not being identified

Tags: python, parallel-processing, fabric

I have a simple fabfile by the name 
**env_fabfile.py**

```
# env_fabfile.py
# makes use of fab env variables 

from fabric.api import env, run
def login():
    env.hosts = ['user@host1:1234', 'user@host2:2345']
    env.passwords = {'user@host1:1234': 'pass1', 'user@host2:2345': 'pass2'}
    env.parallel=True

def run_lsb_release():
    run('lsb_release -a')
```

Now I run the above using the fab command as :

> fab -f env_fabfile.py login run_lsb_release

And it runs perfectly (in parallel) and gives the desired output

Now I wanted to actually calculate the time difference between when the same script is run in serial vs when it is run in parallel. So to do this I wrote the below python script:
**timecal.py**

```
# timecal.py
# runs the fabfile once in serial and calculates the time
# then runs the same file in parallel and calculates the time

from fabric.api import env, run
import time

def login():
    print "in login"
    env.hosts = ['user@host1:1234', 'user@host2:2345']
    env.passwords = {'user@host1:1234': 'pass1', 'user@host2:2345': 'pass2'}

def parallel(status):
    print "in parallel"
    env.parallel=status

def run_lsb_release():
    print "in run"
    run('lsb_release -a')

def do_serial():
    start_time = time.time()
    parallel(False)
    login()
    run_lsb_release()
    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
    return elapsed_time

def do_parallel():
    start_time = time.time()
    parallel(True)
    login()
    run_lsb_release()
    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
    return elapsed_time


if __name__ == '__main__':  
    print "Running in serial mode "
    print "Total time taken ", do_serial()

    print "Running in parallel mode"
    print "Total time taken ", do_parallel()
```

but when I run timecal.py as

> python timecal.py

I get the below on stdout (apart from the print statements in the code)

> No hosts found. Please specify (single) host string for connection:

I don't understand why ? Also how can the script be rectified so that I can achieve what I want to (as stated in the question above)

In case I try a different version of timecal.py, as :

```
from fabric.api import run, settings, env
import time

def do_parallel():
    start_time = time.time()
    env.hosts = ['user@host1:1234', 'user@host2:2345']
    env.passwords = {'user@host1:1234': 'pass1', 'user@host2:2345': 'pass2'}
    env.parallel=True
    run('lsb_release -a')
    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
    return elapsed_time

def do_serial():
    start_time = time.time()
    with settings(host_string='host1', port=1234, user='user', password='pass1'):
        run('lsb_release -a')
    with settings(host_string='host2', port=2345, user='user', password='pass2'):
        run('lsb_release -a')
    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
    return elapsed_time

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    try:
        print "Running in parallel mode"
        print "Total time taken ", do_parallel()

        print "Running in serial mode "
        print "Total time taken ", do_serial()
    except Exception as e:
        print e
```

I get the below error :

> Fatal error: Needed to prompt for the target host connection string (host: None), but input would be ambiguous in parallel mode

I don't understand why is the host: None here ? What is wrong with the code ?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you shouldn't set the `env.hosts` value the way you are currently doing, and `env.passowrds` is super-sketchy (broken maybe?), and [it's recommended to use SSH key-based access](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.5/usage/execution.html#id5), especially [leveraging native SSH config files](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.5/usage/execution.html#leveraging-native-ssh-config-files).

Here's the modified version of your timecal.py script which works as expected, and I'll call out some of the differences below.

```
# timecal.py
# runs the fabfile once in serial and calculates the time
# then runs the same file in parallel and calculates the time

from fabric.api import env, run, execute, parallel
import time

env.use_ssh_config = True
env.roledefs = {
    "my_servers": ['server_1', 'server_2']
}


def run_lsb_release():
    print "in run"
    run('lsb_release -a')


def do_task(task_func):
    start_time = time.time()
    execute(task_func, roles=['my_servers'])
    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
    return elapsed_time


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Running in serial mode "
    print "Total time taken ", do_task(run_lsb_release)

    print "Running in parallel mode"
    print "Total time taken ", do_task(parallel(run_lsb_release))
```

The main difference is using `env.roledefs`, and the SSH config file, rather than hosts & passwords. Those values will NOT work in the parallel execution mode, due to the fact that those tasks are executed in separate threads. [The docs](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.13/usage/parallel.html) are a little thin, but that's basically why you're having this problem.